# How do I arrange columns of HTML table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I made a table that dynamically adds rows to my html table, it dynamically adds a delete button into the row too. I need to arrange the columns when table headings are clicked on!

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <form id="organiser">
      <label id="heading">Organiser</label>
  <br/>
      <br/>
      <label>No:</label>
      <input type="text" id="description"/>
      <br/>
      <label>Importance Level:</label>
      <select id="options1">
        <option value=" 1 " name="1" id="1"> 1 </option>
        <option value=" 2 " name="2" id="2"> 2 </option>
        <option value=" 3 " name="3" id="3"> 3 </option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <label>Due Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="date" />
      <br/>
      <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onClick="addRowToTable();"/>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <table border="1" id="table">
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Importance</th>
        <th>Date Tasks Due</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around with your code and made a plethora of changes (including to HTML), please see [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CfJYf/).

The JavaScript I ended up with is as follows

```
function addRowToTable(table){
    var table = document.getElementById('table'),
        i = table.rows.length,
        tr = table.insertRow(i),
        t0 = tr.insertCell(0),
        t1 = tr.insertCell(1),
        t2 = tr.insertCell(2),
        t3 = tr.insertCell(3),
        t4 = tr.insertCell(4),
        text, elm;

    // Give row unique values
    tr.setAttribute('name', 'txtRow' + i);
    tr.setAttribute('id', 'txtRow' + i);

    // First cell
    text = document.createTextNode( i );
    t0.appendChild( text );

    // Second cell
    text = document.createTextNode( document.getElementById('description').value || 'N/A' );
    t1.appendChild( text );

    // Third cell
    elm = document.getElementById('options1'); // you need to describe what you're trying to do here better
    text = document.createTextNode( elm.value );
    t2.appendChild( text );

    // Fourth cell
    elm = document.getElementById('date');
    text = document.createTextNode( elm.value || 'N/A' );
    t3.appendChild( text );

    // Delete button cell
    elm = document.createElement('input');
    elm.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    elm.setAttribute('value', 'x');
    elm.setAttribute('class', 'delete');
    elm.onclick = function(e){ deleteButton( tr ); };
    t4.appendChild(elm);
}

function sortCol( col ){
    var table = document.getElementById('table'),
        arr, i;
    if( col >= table.rows[0].cells.length) return;

    arr = Array.prototype.map.call(table.rows, function( row ){
        return [row, row.cells[col].textContent];
    });
    arr.shift(); // skip ID, Description..

    arr.sort( function(a, b){
        return a[1].localeCompare( b[1] );
    } );

    for( i = 0; i<arr.length; i = i + 1){
        table.tBodies[0].appendChild( arr[i][0] );
    }
}

function deleteButton( tr ){
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: @ZiggyBird It still isn't complete, e.g. see what happens if you add 2 rows, delete the 1st and add a 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to populate the content of the cells could be this:

```
//Insert tags on cell
var cell2= row.insertCell(2);  
cell2.innerHTML = '<label>Hello </label> <span>World</span>"/>';
```

For big tables maybe you can use this: 
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: @ZiggyBird `innerHTML` is fine if you don't want to attach any event handlers (I'm sure there's other cases, but still). For example, for `secondCell`, technically you could just use: `secondCell.innerHTML = "<span id='txtRow" + iteration + "' name='txtRow" + iteration + "'>" + document.getElementById('description').value + "</span>"`.

Comment: @ZiggyBird Oh yeah, of course, just wanted to point it out :) I always feel better doing it the way you are, but there isn't a problem with using `innerHTML` in your situation. If you were using it on rows that already existed (possibly with elements with events already existing) then it isn't the best to use.